# Monitoring if an application is down

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I would like to monitor if an application is down using an EPL query in Esper. 
The application constantly sends heart beats events every 30 seconds when running. 
If there are no heart beats received after 2 minutes then the application can be considered as down. 
To prevent spamming, output events should only be sent out every 10 minutes as long as the application is down.

I am quite sure its possible to write an EPL query for this using Esper, but I don't know how this query should look like.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think a pattern will suit to detect the heart beat missing (see page that presents solutions on the project home page for example). 
You could use "output first every 10 min" with that.

Comment: This query works with one exception, it needs at least one heart beat to be sent out first in order to work. Any ideas why?
SELECT count(*) FROM KEEPALIVE.win:time(2 MIN)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
OUTPUT EVERY 10 MIN